# All drawings move together in Blender? Is there a way to turn this off?

Tags: animation, 2d

I've been trying to work on a new animation. I'm new to Blender so i'm still learning it. I was drawing my character but then I ran into a problem where when I click one object like the character's head. It selects literally every single drawing in the software so now I can't move anything separately for the animation to work. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? (Oh sorry I forgot and by the way this is for 2D Animation)

Comment: It might help us answer your question if you could add a screenshot or a video demonstrating your problem.

Comment: This is for absolute beginners like yourself. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13UpIjJEE7Oa7x5BiMsjXGW5CGOTDF03-SocRYi4Babs/

Answer (score 2):

In Grease Pencil edit mode: select the strokes you want to split from the rest and then (menu)Stoke -> Separate -> Selected Strokes. The Separate menu has the shortcut "P". You will then have the selected strokes as separate Grease Pencil objects. You can also move them in edit mode, after you select, as you see fit.